# how do I dynamically create the id while creating the text box?

Tags: javascript, input, dynamic

I'm looking at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/npH8X/

```
    <div id='parent'>
    <textarea>txt1</textarea>
    <textarea>txt2</textarea>
    <textarea>txt3</textarea>
    </div>
    <button onClick="addBox()">add textarea</button>

    addBox = function(){
    var textBox = document.createElement("textarea");
    document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(textBox);
    }
```

anybody have javascript example like it, but showing exactly how I might give each of those boxes its own id either at its creation or right afterwards while I'm at it?

I want to create a writer's tool where they can type info into each box and then port all the inputs into one larger container afterwards, so the boxes need ids to do that...

thanks

Comment: *"so the boxes need ids to do that"* - **No they don't.** Give them all a common class and you can select them all with `document.querySelectorAll(".classNameHere")` (or `document.getElementsByClassName()`), and then extract the current values in a loop. Whenever you find yourself wanting to assign a dynamic ID so that other code can access an element via that ID you're probably going down the "wrong" path.

Comment: I don't want them to all go into the box with one click, the user will select which order and which items they want to save there. The tool is meant to brainstorm the order of your outline and then fill the box accordingly, so it may be box 4, box 1, box 7, etc rather than just 1, 2, 3. That's why I thought ids would be best. But then, if they close a box I still have to figure out how to remove it again? Sheesh! (lol)

Comment: what do you think of adding a button along with the box that will add the text to the main box when they click it specifically?

Comment: Or, open new windows that have textareas, and a button that they click to copy what's in the window into the main box and then clear or close that window after?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is set the [**`.id` property**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/id) of the textbox after it is created, but before it is inserted to the DOM. This can correspond to a variable, and automatically increment based off of it:

```js
var count = 3; // Corresponding to the existing textbox count

addBox = function() {
  var textBox = document.createElement("textarea");
  count++;
  textBox.id = count;
  document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(textBox);
  console.log("New element's ID: " + textBox.id);
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <textarea id="1">txt1</textarea>
  <textarea id="2">txt2</textarea>
  <textarea id="3">txt3</textarea>
</div>
<button onClick="addBox()">add textarea</button>
```

However, note that you don't **need** to give your `<textarea>` elements IDs in order to be able to target them. You use [**`document.querySelectorAll()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to return a collection of all textboxes, including those that have been dynamically created:

```js
addBox = function() {
  var textBox = document.createElement("textarea");
  document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(textBox);
}

checkBoxes = function() {
  console.log(document.querySelectorAll("#parent textarea"));
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <textarea>txt1</textarea>
  <textarea>txt2</textarea>
  <textarea>txt3</textarea>
</div>
<button onClick="addBox()">add textarea</button>
<button onClick="checkBoxes()">check boxes</button>
```

Hope this helps! :)

#### Comment Answer:

`.querySelectorAll()` simply returns a node list of all of the `<textarea>` elements. As such, you can access the fourth element with **3** as an index (as it starts from 0). `document.querySelectorAll("#parent textarea")[3]` corresponds to the fourth `<textarea>`, and you can retrieve its contents with the `.value` property:

```js
addBox = function() {
  var textBox = document.createElement("textarea");
  document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(textBox);
}

var box4content;

getBox4 = function() {
  if(document.querySelectorAll("#parent textarea")[3]) {
    box4content = document.querySelectorAll("#parent textarea")[3].value;
  }
  console.log("The variable `box4content` has the value: " +  box4content);
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <textarea>txt1</textarea>
  <textarea>txt2</textarea>
  <textarea>txt3</textarea>
</div>
<button onClick="addBox()">add textarea</button>
<button onClick="getBox4()">get box 4</button>
```

Comment: it does, thanks. So, how would I access box 4 specifically and add its input into a variable for later use elsewhere if it didn't have an id? I'm coming from having learned html4 and learning 5 so I'm trying to retrain my brain away from old habits... ;)

Comment: @RobinJoyWirth -- I've updated my answer to cover this :)

Comment: Awesome. I need to study more on making a variable contain a function, that's the problem with trying to teach this to yourself! Thanks!!!!

Comment: so, how would I make a function to get the number of the box? I imagine something like this but how do I acquire x?        selectBox=function(){boxnum=document.querySelectorAll("#parent textarea")[x];}

Comment: it is supposed to derive from which box they have the focus on, if that helps?

Comment: @Robin -- Don't get confused; the variable assigned to the function plays no difference here (other than syntax); the same would work with `function addBox() { }`. My first answer shows how to get the number of the box; it's simply `count` -- because `count` starts at 3 and gets incremented every time a box is added, it will always be equivalent to the same 'number' as the most recent text box. It depends on **specifically** what you're trying to do with that number, but typically you'd just make use of `.querySelectorAll("#parent textarea")[x]` -- Don't forget you can **loop** over `x`! :)

Comment: I get that part, was just playing with that a bit. What I wonder is, what do I use to create function removeBox to take it off again. I think what I really need is some tutorial that shows how to manipulate dynamic data, such that I could add or subtract boxes that can hold data in them, and that command that allows you to copy the entire box's contents with a click so they could then just paste it into the main box? That might do the trick. It shouldn't be so complex really.

Comment: Here's what I made, so how would I put a function to select the text by clicking a box and then having it copy into the clipboard with a right click? Also, is there a tutorial somewhere that would show me all of this so I dont have to keep botherin' you? lol

Comment: <h4>SAVER BOX</h4>
<textarea id="allbox" style="width: 70%;" rows="20"></textarea>

<div class=tct id=boxes>

<br><br><button onclick="addBox();">CREATE<br>A BOX</button><br><br>
<div id=parent></div>
</div>
</section>
</body></html>

Comment: <script>
function init(){}
var count = 0; // Corresponding to the existing textbox count

addBox = function() {
    var textBox = document.createElement("textarea");
    count++;
    textBox.id = count;
    document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(textBox);
}
</script>

Comment: lol...also is there a tutorial on how to add a comment because when I enter it adds it instead of  allowing continued elaboration....grrrr

Comment: tct is a class in my css that aligns the text to the middle if you wonder

Comment: i can guess that selecting the text is an onclick, so what I really need is just the command that selects it, and also the one you use to copy it with a right click. With those and the command to remove it again, the thing would be done except for styling it, which is not a problem at all ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, tutorials or other off-site resources is considered '[**off-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)' for StackOverflow, as the recommendations would be done to personal opinion. Please refer to the documentation for topics that are considered '[**on-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)', and also review the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, your comments ask for something **completely** different to your initial question, creating a possible [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). To combine them with the initial question would make it far **too broad**, another category of question that's considered '[**off-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)' for StackOverflow. Please break each point down into a specific action, and ask each one as new, individual question. You can link to this question with [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45559066) if it helps to explain your point :)